Non-conformable Arguments Error with tuneR's readWave Function
I'm trying to read 10 .wav files into R using the tuneR package. Nine of the files are reading in just fine, but one is giving me a "non-conformable arguments" error which looks like this:
cclo <- readWave("BirdCalls/CCLO_105291_44k_CN.wav", from = 45, to = 48, units = "seconds", toWaveMC = T)
Error in readBin(con, int, n = 4, size = 1, endian = "little", signed = FALSE) %*%  : 
  non-conformable arguments

I used file.info() to look at the file info for each of my audio files, and they all look very similar (i.e., it's not an issue with this file having a file size of 0, which I saw on a different Stack thread was the cause of someone else's issues). Here's the info from two calls, the bad one and a good one:
Bad:
size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
BirdCalls/CCLO_105291_44k_CN.wav 8814796 FALSE  666 2024-06-24 14:30:11 2024-06-24 14:30:11 2024-10-08 10:07:14  no

Good:
size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
BirdCalls/VESP_110274_44k_CN.wav 5217092 FALSE  666 2017-12-27 17:32:53 2024-09-24 11:25:37 2024-10-08 10:00:38  no

I looked through the code of the readWave function itself and couldn't determine where in the function it might be throwing the error. Any ideas of what could be going wrong? The file came from the Macauley Library. Here is the link if you want to try it for yourself (you'd have to put in a request for the file): https://macaulaylibrary.org/asset/621379386

Try using traceback()  .  But can you post the offending file somewhere for us to play with?  In the meantime, try just calling readBin(con, .....) to see what you can read from the file, avoiding the %*% operator and whatever value follows it in the readWave source code.     Note "non-conformable" here suggests whatever readBin returned is of different length that whatever follows the matrix product operator

Try to conver your wav files to RIFF files
i.e. use this: https://www.freeconvert.com/audio-converter/download

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
